# CollectionAssert.AreEqual точность сравнения элементов списков C#

Tags: c#, mstest

Столкнулся с проблемой при сравнении 2х списков в тесте. 
использую: `CollectionAssert.AreEqual(List1,List2)`.

можно ли как то влиять на точность с которой происходит сравнение элементов? например List1 { 2.333333, 3.36363636 } (результат вычислений) и List2 { 2.3333, 3.3636 } (ожидаемое значение) разумеется такое сравнение не проходит.

Comment: [перегрузка с компарером](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms243753.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У метода `CollectionAssert.AreEqual()` есть ряд перегрузок, в том числе ти те, которые принимают интерфейс IComparer. Вам надо написать свою реализацию этого интерфейса, а в ней описать свою логику сравнения, например с максимально допустимой разницей сравниваемых элементов. Правда, обобщённых IComparer ни одна из перегрузок не принимает, но этот недостаток не смертелен.

Пример:

```
    public class MyComparer : IComparer
    {
        private const double Tolerance = 0.001;

        public int Compare(object x, object y)
        {
            double x1 = (double) x;
            double y1 = (double) y;

            if (Math.Abs(x1 - y1) <= Tolerance)
                return 0;

            return x1 > y1 ? 1 : -1;
        }
    }

    .... 

    var first = new List<double> { 2.335333, 3.36363636 };
    var second = new List<double> { 2.3333, 3.3636 };
    CollectionAssert.AreEqual(first, second, new MyComparer());
```

Comment: буду благодарен за пример. только учусь

Comment: @Роман  обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось.